# unable to run the react project- the following error enoent ENOENT

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, npm, package.json

Whenever I am running npm start in my project it displays the following error

> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! path
> /home/abhi/package.json npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no
> such file or directory, open '/home/abhi/package.json' npm ERR! enoent
> This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/abhi/.npm/_logs/2020-12-17T04_15_31_411Z-debug.log

```
abhi@Abhi:~/Projects/demo1$
```

I tried everything to fix the issue but did not find a solution.
what I am missing in JSON.package ??

Comment: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/abhi/package.json' means there is file to read. Are u sure that you have package.json in your product directory?

Answer (score 2):

You need to navigate to your app directory to be able to run npm start.
seems you are running it out of that directory.
type
cd "your app path"
then
npm start

Answer (score 0):

is your package initialised at all? did you run

```
npm init
```

or your dependencies and their versions are correct? and the node version too?

Clear everything from the cache and try installing again

```
npm cache clean
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the same error. I renamed the folder, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio code, go to the app directory and right click the folder and select "**open with Visual Studio Code**", then run in terminal `npm start` and it should work.

If "**open with Visual Studio Code**" doesn't show, you need to reinstall it and during the reinstallation there will be 4 checkboxes, check them and install.

Answer (score 0):

You should make npm install in the app directory so type cd your path in the terminal and make sure your in the directory of the app.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34620977)

Answer (score 0):

check npm is downloaded or not -  npm -v
if yes just update npm once-npm install -g npm
and then try again.

thanx.

Comment: Please use this info https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to make your post more easily readable and maybe generally improve according to [answer]. Consider taking the highly recommended [tour].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).